# How to read line (from a file) and then append + print in python?

Tags: python

```
for line in file:
    print line
```

In the code above when I change it to:

```
for line in file:
    print line + " just a string"
```

This only appends "just a string" to the last line

PS: Python newbie

Comment: Can you please post the actual code that is causing the problem, including the "something?" Thanks

Comment: It would be useful if you would also include the actual output of this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterating over a file includes the line endings, so just remove them:

```
for line in file:
  print line.rstrip("\n"), "something"
```

Note that print will append its own newline, so even without appending "something" you'd want to do this (or use sys.stdout.write instead of print).  You may also use `line.rstrip()` if you want to remove all trailing whitespace (e.g. spaces and tabs too).

Documentation:

> Files support the iterator protocol. Each iteration returns the same result as file.readline(), and iteration ends when the readline() method returns an empty string.

- http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline (quoted text is below the methods)

Comment: Thanks, your answer was useful, there was some problem in the text file (as I copied from web page -> excel -> text file) so it was appending to the last line but definitely I needed rstrip() ;)

Answer (score 0):

The line received through the iterator includes the newline character at the end - so if you want "something" to be appended on the same line you will need to cut this off.

```
for line in file:
    print line[:-1] + " something"
```

Comment: This breaks on the last line of the file, if it doesn't have a newline, by removing data.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can append 'something' at the end of each line:**

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("dat.txt"):
    print line.rstrip(), ' something'
```

If you want to append 'something' to line and then print the line:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("dat.txt"):
    line = line.rstrip() + ' something'
    print line
    # now you can continue processing line with something appended to it
```

dat.txt file:

```
> cat dat.txt
one
two and three
four -
five
.
```

output:

```
> ./r.py
one  something
two and three  something
four -  something
five  something
.  something
```

Comment: I want to append string "something" to the line and print.